# Sequels "where" referring to include model column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, include, sequelize.js

I have the following model using node.js with Sequelize (@3.3.2):

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Topic = sequelize.define("Topic", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Topic.hasMany(models.Section, {as: 'sections'});
            }
        }
    });

    return Topic;
};

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Section = sequelize.define("Section", {
        previewImg: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Section.belongsTo(models.Topic);
                Section.belongsToMany(models.Domain, {through: 'SectionDomainsExclusive', as: 'exclusiveDomains'});
            }
        }
    });

    return Section;
};

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Domain = sequelize.define("Domain", {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

    return Domain;
};
```

So a Topic has many Sections and a Section can have a list of "exclusive" Domains. 
The required functionality is:

> If there are no exclusive domains (no relation), the domain is visible in all these domains. If there are one or more exclusive domains assigned, the section shall be visible to only these domains

Now I want to retrieve the topics along with the sections, that are visible:

```
models.Topic.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.Section,
            as: 'sections',
            include: [{
                model: models.Domain,
                required: false,
                as: 'exclusiveDomains',
            }],
            where: {
                'exclusiveDomains.id': {
                    $or: {
                        $eq: 3,
                        $eq: null
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }).then(function (objList) {
        ///...
    });
```

So I want a LEFT JOIN (required: false) on the Domains with the alias "exclusiveDomains" and then WHERE the whole query to the results in which there was no exclusive domains found (NULL) or there is an the section is visible to domain 3, which is my domain.

I cannot put the WHERE part in the include, because this would restrict the results of the join only and I could not distinguish, if the section has no exclusive domains listet or if my domain (3) is just not in the list.

Unfortunately Sequelize always puts "section." infront of my WHERE, so this results in the following error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: sections.exclusiveDomains.id

The SQL-String should look something like this:

```
SELECT `Topic`.`id`,
      `sections`.`id`                                                 AS
        `sections.id`,
      `sections.exclusiveDomains`.`id`                                AS
        `sections.exclusiveDomains.id`,
      `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive`.`sectionid` AS
        `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive.SectionId`,
      `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive`.`domainid`  AS
        `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive.DomainId`
    FROM   `topics` AS `Topic`
      INNER JOIN `sections` AS `sections`
        ON `Topic`.`id` = `sections`.`topicid`
      INNER JOIN `sectionusergroup` AS `sections.usergroups.SectionUsergroup`
        ON `sections`.`id` = `sections.usergroups.SectionUsergroup`.`sectionid`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `sectiondomainsexclusive` AS `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive`
        ON `sections`.`id` = `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive`.`sectionid`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `domains` AS `sections.exclusiveDomains`
        ON `sections.exclusiveDomains`.`id` = `sections.exclusiveDomains.SectionDomainsExclusive`.`domainid`
    WHERE (`sections.exclusiveDomains`.`id` = 3 OR `sections.exclusiveDomains`.`id` IS NULL);
```

Unfortunately I cannot get the `sections.exclusiveDomains`.`id` part, because Sequelize always puts section in front, so it looks like `sections`.`exclusiveDomains.id`, which is obviously wrong.

What can I do?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Raw queries are the best approach.

```
where:["sections.exclusiveDomains.id = 3 OR sections.exclusiveDomains.id is null", null]
```

There is probably a cleaner way to extract the fully qualified names, but for now this seems to work a treat!

Comment: Hi Anthony, Many thanks. I was not aware that such raw queries are possible. This is definitely better than looping the array afterwards ;) Thanks!

Comment: _"Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed."_,
_"Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed."_
